# Transaction Log backup chains and one off full backups

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I am trying to create a backup plan consisting of full, differential and log backups however i know one off full backups are taken whenever fixes are done to the database.

Dors anyone know whether these one off backups will cause a problem to the maintenance plan i want to implement

Answer (score 4):

If the one-off/out-of-sequence backups are taken with [copy_only option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/copy-only-backups-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16), it should not affect the backup/restore plan. Without using copy_only, the one-off backup will be your starting point for differential restores.

```
BACKUP DATABASE dbname
TO DISK = 'c:\backups\dbname_oneoff.bak'
WITH COPY_ONLY;
```